# Conditionally start a new table row

Tags: ruby, html-table, haml

I am trying to create a two column table. I want to put an item's data into each 'column' thus I only want to start a new row when the count of the items is even.

So I'm looping through a list of items and advancing a counter with each pass. When the counter % 2 == 0 I want to start a new row (%tr).

```
- items.each do |item|
  - if counter % 2  == 0
    %tr{class: "something"}
    %td= item[:value1]
    %td= item[:value2]
  - else
    %td= item[:value1]
    %td= item[:value2]
  - counter += 1
```

This almost produces the desired effect. I understand why the first tr is created because the subsequent td tags are at the same tab depth. But if I move them into the same depth then only the first two td tags are wrapped into the first row and the susbsequent tds are placed into a new row (probably by the browser). Indenting all the td tags to the same level, in both sides of the if clause will cause HAML to crashes (returns nothing).

```
 <tr class="something"></tr>
 <tr><td>1</td>
 <td>2</td>
 <td>3</td>
 <td>4>/td>
 </tr>
```

How then can I accomplish this?

Comment: didn't understand what you're trying to say, but try to do the iteration with `.each_with_index` instead of the counter.

Comment: You should make the question more concise. I didn't feel like reading through it.

Comment: An example of what your input looks like, and what output you want is a great way to get a quick answer.

Comment: The input is X groups of items where the number of items in a group will vary and not always contain an even number. I am using a coounter variable to keep track of the total number of items. I think that rather than use a conditional to determine is a new row is needed I should count the items ahead of time while in each group and insert a blank set of cells to even the group out. Then I can take the items 2 at a time as Stefan suggested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [`Enumerable#each_slice`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_slice):

```
- items.each_slice(2) do |sliced_items|
  %tr{class: "something"}
    - sliced_items.each do |item|
      %td= item[:value1]
      %td= item[:value2]
```

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since I've done haml, but shouldn't something like this do the job?

```
- items.each do |item|
  %tr{class: "something"}
    %td= item[:value1]
    %td= item[:value2]
```

This way the `%tr` is automatically encapsulating two `%td`s at a time.